# I am trying to get the woocommerce to list (ul) subcategories to show under the main categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to list (ul) categories with their respective subcategory if they have one. How can I use the code below to include subcategories on the archive-product.php
With the code below I am getting categories and subcategories at the same level. Dinnerware, Glassware and flatware are subcategories of Table settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srswm.png)

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'taxonomy'          => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
    );
$result = get_terms( $args );
?>
```

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

            <?php
                foreach ( $result as $cat ) {
                    if ( 'Uncategorized' !== $cat->name ) {
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $cat, 'product_cat' );
                    $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $shop_catalog_img_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'shop_catalog' );
                    $cat_img = $shop_catalog_img_arr[0];
                        ?>
                    
                    
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                                <?php echo $cat->name; ?> 
                            </a></li>
                        
                    

                <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>

                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a class to the `<li>` if the term has a parent and therefore is a subcategory. With this class, you can set the way it looks in your CSS and make it look "subcategory"-like:

```
<!-- code before -->

<li <?php if( $cat->parent !== 0 ) { echo 'class="child_cat" '; } ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
        <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
    </a>
</li>

<!-- code after -->
```

When `$cat` has a parent using `$cat->parent` the class will be added. In your style.css you do the adjustments of the style:

```
.child_cat { font-size: 0.9rem; padding-left: 2.5rem; }
```

This way the subcategories will have a smaller font-size and a padding on the left side.

---

**Edit:**

You want to have the subcategories listed below their respective parent. I would suggest to use `get_terms` twice, one time for getting the parents, another time to get the childs. Loop through both of them. Your code can look like this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

<?php

$parent_arguments = array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => true );
$parent_terms = get_terms('product_cat', $parent_arguments );

foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) {

    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $parent_term, "product_cat" ).'">'.$parent_term->name.'</a></li>'; // Parent term

    $child_arguments = array( 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id, 'hide_empty' => true );
    $child_terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $child_arguments );

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
            echo '<li class="child_cat"><a href="'.get_term_link( $child_term, "product_cat" ).'">'.$child_term->name.'</a></li>'; // Child term
        }
    echo '</ul>';

} ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but with this code add the class to the whole list.

Comment: This sounds like your IF always gets true. I edited the if statement in my answer, does it work for you with using `!== 0`? The `$cat->parent` gives you the ID of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks. It added the class to the subcategories. Now, how to make them appear under their parent? the whole list is showing in alphabetic order (categories and subcategories all together - see image above)

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps you out!